# Finding the regular points of a rational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (irreducible, quasi-projective) varieties (over an algebraically closed field $k$), and $\phi: X \to Y$ be a rational map. I think I understand what it means for $\phi$ to be regular at a point $x \in X$, but I'm lost as to how to prove that $x$ *is* (or *isn't*) a regular point of $\phi$, when I am given a single representative of $\phi$.

For example, suppose $X = Y = \mathbb{P}^2$ is the projective plane, and $\phi$ is the rational map determined by $\phi([x : y: z]) = [yz : zx : xy]$. This uniquely defines a rational map since $\mathbb{P}^2$ is irreducible and the equation makes sense away from $P = \{ [1 : 0 : 0], [0 : 1 : 0], [0 : 0 : 1] \}$, which is a closed set. I can see that $\phi$ is a birational equivalence (and even an involution!), and it seems intuitive that $\phi$ cannot be regular on $P$. But how do I prove this rigorously?

Then, for a twist, consider the line $L \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ which satisfies the equation $x + y + z = 0$. Clearly, $L \cap P = \emptyset$, and $\phi(L)$ is the conic $xy + yz + zx = 0$, and $P \subset \phi(L)$. It turns out $\phi$ restricted to $\phi(L)$ is a *morphism* of varieties $\phi(L) \to L$, because we've thrown away enough of the obstructions to regularisation. So regularity seems to be something a bit more subtle than staring at polynomials... but the way I showed that this restriction did turn $\phi$ into an honest morphism was precisely that: I fiddled about with polynomials and equations until I got a consistent set which covered the whole curve. Is there a better / more general way of finding the points at which a a rational map is regular?

Comment: Restrict to an open affine neighborhood and see if you can prove or disprove that the morphism restricts to a morphism of affines. At least, in principle.

Comment: The restricted morphism is from $L$ to $\phi(L)$ and not, as you wrote , the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late ,I know, but as for your question about the domain of the "standard quadratic transformation", you might be interested in the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440296/cremona-transformations-are-birational-maps/442703#442703) and its answer. Basically, you consider the induced morphism
\begin{split}
\phi_{cone}: \Bbb{A}^3 &\rightarrow \Bbb{A}^3\\
(x,y,z) & \mapsto (yz,zx,xy)
\end{split}
and deduce that every extension of $\phi$ to $\Bbb{P}^2$ would have to map $(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ to the "point" $(0:0:0)$, which is of course impossible.

Also, there is a general criterion for deciding whether or not a point is in the domain of some rational map, based on the relation of "dominance" between local rings (cf. [Fulton](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf), Proposition 6.6.11).

> **Proposition:** Let $F: X \dashrightarrow Y$ be a dominating rational map between varieties. Then a point $P \in X$ belongs to the domain of $F$ and $F(P)=Q$, if and only if the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P(X)$ dominates the local ring $\tilde{F}(\mathcal{O}_Q(Y))$, where $\tilde{F}: k(Y) \rightarrow k(X)$ denotes the induced embedding of function fields.

However, I am not sure if this result is too helpful in practice.

Answer (score 2):

a) The restriction of $\phi$ to *any* curve $C$ disjoint from $P$ is a regular morphism $C\to \mathbb P^2$.
b) The restriction of $\phi$ to  any *smooth* curve $S$ is a regular morphism $S\to \mathbb P^2$, **even if** $S$ **contains a point of** $P$.
This is a very important property of **smooth curves** : rational maps from them into projective varieties are actually regular, i.e. are morphisms.
Note carefully that this is completely false for singular curves or smooth varieties of dimension $\geq 2$.

For  your example of the line $L$, both  a) and b) apply and you needn't  "*fiddle about with polynomials and equations*" !

**References**
[Hartshorne](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&redir_esc=y), Chapter I, Proposition 6.8, page 43 .
 or
 [Shafarevich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540548122), Volume 1, Chapter II, §3, Corollary 1 to Theorem 3, page 110 .