# Cremona transformations are birational maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Consider the following map, which is a Cremona transformation: 
$$
\begin{split}
f\colon & \mathbb P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^2 \\
& (x:y:z) \mapsto (xy: xz: yz)
\end{split}
$$

I have to prove the following:

> **1.** The domain is $\mathbb P^2 \setminus \{(1:0:0), (0:1:0), (0:0:1)\}$.
>
> **2.** The map cannot be extended to all $\mathbb P^2$.
>
> **3.** The map is birational by finding its inverse.

Well, point **(1)** is clear ($xy=xz=yz=0$ implies that two of $x,y,z$ are 0). What about point **2**? I do not know how to answer. How could I extend this map to the three special points found in point **1**? Why is this impossible?

Finally, the inverse. Is there an easy trick to find it? I've tried to solve the system in homogeneous coordinates but I think that maybe there is a faster way...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the first point $(1:0:0)$ look at the limits of $(1:y:z)\mapsto (y:z:yz)$ along different lines $y=mz$. You get $(mz:z:mz^2)=(m:1:mz)\rightarrow(m:1:0)$. For the inverse, yes, you can just solve the system in the different charts.

Comment: For the inverse, one trick is to write the map in the form $(x:y:z) \mapsto (\frac{1}{z} : \frac{1}{y} : \frac{1}{x})$. Do you notice anything about this map?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Your remark is fine, I didn't notice it. By the way, I still do not know how to use it. How can I use this information? Thanks.

Comment: @RGB: thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe it's time for a (reasonably complete) answer.

Consider the open subvariety $U_{YZ}:=\Bbb{P}^2 \setminus V(YZ)$ (i.e. $\Bbb{P}^2$ with both the $Y$-axis and the $Z$-axis removed). The rational map $f: \Bbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow \Bbb{P}^2$ can be represented on $U_{YZ}$ by the morphism

\begin{split}
U_{YZ} &\rightarrow U_Z:=\Bbb{P}^2 \setminus V(Z)\\
(x:y:z) &\mapsto (x/z:x/y:1)
\end{split}
which shows that $f$ is defined on all of $U_{YZ}$. Similarly, you find that $f$ is defined on all of $\Bbb{P}^2 \setminus \{(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)\}$, and the only thing left to check for **1.** and **2.** is that $f$ cannot be extended to all of $\Bbb{P}^2$. One possible explanation is the following.

Consider the morphism
\begin{split}
f_{cone}: \Bbb{A}^3 &\rightarrow \Bbb{A}^3\\
(x,y,z) &\mapsto (xy,xz,yz)
\end{split}
which maps every point of the form $(\lambda,0,0),(0,\mu,0)$ or $(0,0,\nu)$ to the point $(0,0,0)$.
Like every morphism of varieties, $f_{cone}$ is already uniquely determined by its restriction to any non-empty open subset, e.g. by its restriction to $\Bbb{A}^3 \setminus \{(\lambda,0,0),(0,\mu,0),(0,0,\nu) \; \vert \; \lambda,\mu,\nu \in k\} \subset \Bbb{A}^3$.

But $f_{cone}$ restricted to $\Bbb{A}^3 \setminus \{(\lambda,0,0),(0,\mu,0),(0,0,\nu) \; \vert \; \lambda,\mu,\nu \in k\}$ induces the morphism representing the rational map $f$, as described above. Hence every extension of $f$ to a morphism defined on all of $\Bbb{P}^2$ would have to map the points $(1:0:0),(0:1:0)$ and $(0:0:1)$ to "$(0:0:0)$", which is impossible, and consequently, the points $(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ cannot be in the domain of $f$.

For **3.**, you simply use the "trick" mentioned by Asal. Let $U_{XYZ}:=\Bbb{P}^2 \setminus V(XYZ)$ (i.e. $\Bbb{P}^2$ without the coordinate axes). On $U_{XYZ}$, we can represent $f$ as
$$
(x:y:z) \mapsto (xy:xz:yz)=1/(xyz)(xy:xz:yz)=(1/z:1/y:1/x)
$$
and from this, you can read off the inverse of $f_{\vert U_{XYZ}}$ directly.

Comment: Really nice answer, thank you. I have understood everything; just for sake of completeness, let me add that - concerning point 3 - the inverse of $F\vert_{U_{XYZ}}$ is simply itself, as an easy calculation shows. Now it's all clear, thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @Romeo, I'm glad to hear it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not permitted to comment now, so I have to write an answer as a complement of Nils’s answer. Indeed I don’t understand Nils’s answer of 2, since I am not a specialist in this field.

I think the argument below is easier to understand for me.

Suppose the map can be extended to include $(1,0,0)$ and we denote the extended map by $\psi: U\rightarrow \mathbb P^2$. Now $U_i=\{(x_0,x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb P^2|x_i\neq 0\}$ is an open covering of $\mathbb P^2$. So one of its preimage contains $(1,0,0)$. This is not symmetric but I will just check the case of $U_0$. $\psi^{-1}(U_0)$ contains $(U_1\cap U_2)\cup \{(1,0,0)\}$ and is open. So $(1,0,0)\in D(f)\subseteq \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\cup (U_1\cap U_2)$. Assume $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_0^n+\sum_{u+v+w=n,w<n}a_{uvw}x_1^u x_2^v x_0^w$. Let $x_0=1$ and $x_1=0$ we are reduced to $1+\sum_{v+w=n,w<n}a_{0vw}x_2^v$. This polynomial has finitely many roots and so we have a contradiction.

This method is the first one coming into my mind. I will appreciate it if anyone could give some general theory!